# HDFS command to move non-hidden files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there a way to move the contents of a directory in HDFS without moving the hidden files/folders within, preferably with a simple command (not a Java app)?

Comment: well, for the first part you can try https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/distcp2.html. no idea if it moves hiddent files or not

Comment: Nope, both commands copy hidden files and folders too. Hence my question.

Comment: one dumb way would be to change permission of hidden files, copy the files, then reset permission

Comment: I'm now doing it using the Java API as it does not seem to be supported in the command line tools.

Comment: you have a command to do that in the api?

Comment: You can use use `GlobFilter("[!.]*")` and use that filter in the `listStatus` method. That gets the job done.